# Running a container's ELF file without container

Tags: linux, containers, elf

I got an ELF file of type
`ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, stripped` which I want to run in a normal regular linux machine (not a container)

Sadly I get the error `No such file or directory` when trying to execute.

I eventually want to debug said ELF and it will be harder to do in a container.

Was googling for hours and couldnt find a simple solution.

Comment: Notice that the file is an "shared object", which is a shared library (a.k.a. a DLL). You can't execute it, you need a program ("executable") that is linked to the library.

Comment: You're right. Is there any simple way to run that? It is even got a main function

Comment: You can't "run" a library, end of story really. And while a library *might* have a `main` function it's not special like it is in an executable program, and won't be called automatically.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are mistaken: this is an executable, and you *can* run it.

Answer (score 2):

> `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, stripped`

This binary is linked to use [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/), which is not installed on your system.

> `No such file or directory`

This error is slightly confusing. What's missing is not your binary, but the *iterpreter* (`/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`) which it requires.

It may be possible to install musl *in parallel* with existing GLIBC, though I didn't find a definitive yes/no answer.

Comment: I ended up running it on Alpine which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

musl is used to compile portable static binaries. Something went wrong with the compilation of the program you are trying to run. The flag '--static' should have been passed to the program that was compiled, which would result in a

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

An example on how to compile such a program:

```
CC=musl-gcc CFLAGS="--static" ./Configure
make
```